# What is the meaning of "In life, that is"?

Tags: meaning

In American parody teen comedy film *Not Another Teen Movie (2001)*, Austin and Malik played a bet on Jake.

> Austin: I'll pick the most hopeless girl at this school and I'll bet
>   that you can't turn her into prom queen.
>
> Jake: You're on, Austin.
>
> Malik: I'll bet you lose that bet but learn a much more valuable
>   lesson, and win. **In life, that is**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "**I'll bet you lose that bet but learn a much more valuable lesson, and win in life**".

"**[that is (to say)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that%20is%20(to%20say))**" is used to introduce or follow a clarification, interpretation, or correction of something already said. Malik clarifies that he's referring to life.